# 32-bit java on win 7

Tags: java, windows-7, windows-7-x64

How do I make a 32-bit java 7 as the default in a 64-bit Windows 7?
When I type in java at the command prompt - it seems to look to a 64-bit java(which I have uninstalled) by default:

```
could not open "c:\program files\java\jre7\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

I am not able to locate how or why is it looking for this specific path.
The JAVA_HOME and PATH contain no reference to it.

How do I make it search for the 32-bit JDK that has been referred to in JAVA_HOME instead?

Comment: Can you show us your `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` settings?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [this tutorial](http://www.robertsindall.co.uk/blog/setting-java-home-variable-in-windows/) for setting the `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` on Windows 7.

From [this site](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/environment_variables.html):

> NOTES: The JDK's "bin" directory should be listed before "c:\windows\system32" and "c:\windows" in the PATH. This is because some older Windows systems provide their own Java runtime (which is often out-dated) in these directories (try search for "java.exe" in your computer!).

Please update your `PATH` system (*not* user) variable to include the location of your 32 bit Java 7 JDK.  Both `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` should be system variables.

It sounds like Windows may still be picking up on your 64 bit Java 7.

Comment: Does updating the user environment variables for JAVA_HOME work?

Answer (score 0):

Update in enviromental variables JAVA_HOME as C:/program files/java/jdk version.
And JRE_HOME as C:/Program files/java/jdk version/jre.